# Using resource artefacts from plugin in main Grails project

Tags: jquery, grails, plugins, module, resources

I am looking for a way to reference modules I am defining inside of a plugin from my main project.

To be more specific, we have a UI plugin that houses a bunch of UI controls. I want to move all my javascript dependancies for these controls (such as jQuery) into the UI plugin, and be able to reference them in my main project, something like

```
dependsOn 'uiplugin-jQuery'
```

Is there a way to do this or do I need to have all my resource modules declared in the main project?

This is using Grails and the Resources 1.2.1 plugin.

Comment: Yes you can do it. Recently came across a [**similar question**](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22926471/2051952). Also make sure you upgrade resources plugin to 1.2.7 (latest) because older versions has a major [vulnerability](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/IMPORTANT-CVE-2014-0053-Information-Disclosure-in-Grails-applications-td4654254.html). With latest version of Grails 2.3.7 you get the latest resources plugin by default.

Comment: I've managed to get it to be recognized, but now I am running into another issue. The taglib I made requires a module, but the taglib itself is conditional based on <sec:ifloggedin>. Right now, I am getting a ton of disposition errors, telling me head/defer is already rendered. Any idea what this is about?

Also feel free to make an answer so I can give you proper credit.

Comment: I won't be able to know the actual issue until details added, preferably as a separate question altogether. I assume you have your resources with header disposition in plugin for javascript resources I would not put as disposition header if feasible.

Comment: Well I am trying to hoist an object to the top since it contains a lot of variables needed for the taglib. I'm going to mess with it more, if I can't figure it out I'll post a question.